# jekyll long pagination, how to shorten it?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I solve the following problem, for example if I have many pages, my pagination looks like this:

**`< 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 >`**

Is it possible to shorten this like normal pagination,

**`< 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7  ... 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 >`**

I mean, strip the pages, and if we are in the middle, like this:

**`< 7, 8, 9, 10 ... 22,23, 24, 25, 26 >`**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125878/can-i-have-a-proper-nice-tiled-pagination-in-jekyll-using-liquid-templates/31972386#31972386. If it works please upvote the answer so that this question can be flagged as a duplicate (and redirect there).