# Can I have a proper nice tiled pagination in Jekyll using Liquid templates?

Tags: pagination, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I've found this nice jekyll theme: http://www.jacoporabolini.com/emerald/ with good looking pagination. Unfortunately is only good looking when there is a small number of pages. In case of my blog this looks like this: [image]

Not surprisingly because the code looks like this:

```
{% for page in (1..paginator.total_pages) %}
```

And it should like more like this:

```
 {% for page in (min(1,paginator.page-3)..max(paginator.page+3,paginator.total_pages)) %}
```

The problem is, I don't think there is something like `min` and `max` in Liquid or even arithmetic operators like `+` or `-`. I was searching though the documentation and couldn't find `min` or `max.` I've also checked many themes and all they offer is this naive pagination, no pagination at all and first|current|next type of pagination. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025597/liquid-and-arithmetic) will help?

Comment: If the correct answer is indeed correct then yes, it will solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: I haven't actually tried it yet, but I'm working on my own site's pagination and it's at least a good place to start.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963027/jekyll-long-pagination-how-to-shorten-it

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Liquid `{% include %}` that does what you are looking for. [Jekyll Paginator Links](https://github.com/Shadowen/jekyll-paginator-links).

I based it on the logic you used (min/max), but it has a bit more math built in as well. It's customizable with CSS so it should be able to do what you have described. I hope it does what you need it to! If not, submit an issue on GitHub.